# A function to obtain all leaf node properties of an object in an array of string in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, nested

Request you to please help in building a function in javascript to obtain the mentioned output from the input given.

INPUT : An object (possibly a nested object)

example :

{

"message":"string" ,

"data1": {

```
    "Output1": {

        "leaf1": "abc",

        "Leaf2": "123"

    }

}
```

"data2": {

```
    "Output2": {

        "leaf3": "abc",

        "leaf4": "123"

    }

}
```

}

OUTPUT : An array of string

Example :
str= ["message", "data1.Output1.leaf1", "data1.Output1.leaf2" , "data2.Output2.leaf3","data2.Output2.leaf4"]

Comment: You ask for help, but show nothing you have done. Please show your efforts and where exactly you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this it will work

```js
const getBranches = (data, prefix=[]) => {
  if (typeof(data) !== 'object') {
    return prefix.join('.')
  }
  return Object.entries(data).flatMap(([k, v]) => getBranches(v, [...prefix, k]))

  }

  const data = {
    "message": "string",
    "data1": {
      "Output1": {
        "leaf1": "abc",
        "Leaf2": "123"
      }
    },
    "data2": {
      "Output2": {
        "leaf3": "abc",
        "leaf4": "123"
      }
    }
  }


console.log(getBranches(data))
```

Second version

```js
const data = {
  "message": "string",
  "data1": {
    "Output1": {
      "leaf1": [{
        "b": {
          "c": "12"
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  "data2": {
    "Output2": {
      "leaf3": "abc",
      "leaf4": "123"
    }
  }
}
const getBranches = (data, prefix = []) => {
  if (typeof(data) !== 'object') {
    return prefix.join('.')
  }
  return Object.entries(data).flatMap(([k, v]) => Array.isArray(data) ? getBranches(v, [...prefix]) : getBranches(v, [...prefix, k]))
}

console.log(getBranches(data))
```

Comment: @ArushRaj what upgrade?

Comment: Thank You! It worked well, but now there is a small upgrade that is needed. Instead of having nested object with normal leaf nodes. The input is 
const data = {
    "message": "string",
    "data1": {
      "Output1": {
        "leaf1": [{"b" : {"c": "12"}}]
      }
    },
    "data2": {
      "Output2": {
        "leaf3": "abc",
        "leaf4": "123"
      }
    }
  }
And output should be - 
str= ["message", "data1.Output1.leaf1.b.c", "data1.Output1.leaf2" , "data2.Output2.leaf3","data2.Output2.leaf4"]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping, but adding on to it there is one more requirement - to include all the nodes in the str. So the ouput str= ["message", "data1" ,"data1.Output1", "data1.Output1.leaf1","data1.Output1.leaf1.b",,"data1.Output1.leaf1.b.c", "data1.Output1.leaf2","data2","data2.Output2","data2.Output2.leaf3","data2.Output2.leaf4"]